# Set size graphic in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, jitter

I made a graphic with height and weight of person, the max of weight is 110 (beacause the the heaviest is 110) but I should set the graphic go until 150

`ap90+geom_jitter(width=2, size=0.5)+labs(subtitle = "Anni 90", y="Peso", x="Altezza", title="Relazione altezza peso")`

Thanks you

P.s.
Sorry for my english

Comment: Try to include a reproducible example with some mock up data. I can see you are using ggplot2, it would be helpful to state it explicitly in your code with `library(ggplot2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `mtcars` as example data you can set the limits of the axis via the `limits` argument in `scale_x/y_continuous`. Try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg)) + 
  geom_jitter(width=2, size=0.5) +
  # Set limits of yaxis to c(0, 60)
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 60)) +
  labs(subtitle = "Anni 90", y="Peso", x="Altezza", title="Relazione altezza peso")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: it gevis me an error: Errore:    Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Comment: This error occurs if your variables are not numbers but are coded as characters or factors instead. Convert your vars to numeric using  `as.numeric()`.

Comment: (: My pleasure. If you want do me a favor: Mark the question as answered. Besides giving me some credit it shows others with a similar problem that the solution worked and removes the question from the queue of questions still waiting for an answer.